# Groupby with no Metrics

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the following in all string format.

```
Doc     Material    Date1   Date2   Date3
111     AAA     2018-01-02  NaT     NaT
111     AAA     NaT     2018-01-02  NaT
111     AAA     NaT     NaT     2018-01-03
```

I want the following.

```
Doc     Material    Date1   Date2   Date3
111     AAA     2018-01-02  2018-01-02  2018-01-03
```

I want to do a groupby type operation but all my fields are strings.

Comment: df.groupby(['Doc','Mat']).first(), first will ignore then nan

Answer (score 2):

If all your fields are strings, then you first need to replace the `'NaT'` strings with the proper `pd.NaT` value, and then you can use `groupby()` and `first()`:

```
df.replace('NaT', pd.NaT, inplace=True)

df.groupby('Doc').first()
```

Yields:

```
    Material       Date1       Date2       Date3
Doc                                             
111      AAA  2018-01-02  2018-01-02  2018-01-03
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the dataframe you desire. I stack the dataframe, removing NAs, then unstack the dataframe to your desired format.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[111, 'AAA', '2018-01-02', np.nan, np.nan],
                  [111, 'AAA', np.nan, '2018-01-02', np.nan],
                  [111, 'AAA', np.nan, np.nan, '2018-01-03']], columns = ['Doc', 'Material', 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3'])

df2 = (df.set_index(['Doc', 'Material']).stack().reset_index() # get stacked version with NAs removed
        .groupby(['Doc', 'Material', 'level_2'])[0].max().unstack(level=2).reset_index() # unstack back to original format
      )
```

The resulting DataFrame looks like this.

```
level_2  Doc Material       Date1       Date2       Date3
0        111      AAA  2018-01-02  2018-01-02  2018-01-03
```

Answer (score 0):

WeNYoBen was the easiest method.  I used: df.groupby(['Doc','Mat']).first().reset_index()